# Sharepoint 2010 SP2 upgrade issue - PSConfig failed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm running SharePoint 2010 SP2 upgrade (`oserversp2010-kb2687453-fullfile-x64-en-us`) on my DEV single server farm . After installing the binaries, reboot and run `psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force`

> Command failed with below error
>
> SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard version 14.0.6009.1000. Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
>
> Performing configuration task 1 of 4 Initializing SharePoint Products upgrade... Waiting to get a lock to upgrade the farm. Successfully initialized SharePoint Products upgrade. Performing configuration task 2 of 4 Initiating the upgrade sequence... Failed to initiate the upgrade sequence. An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown. Additional exception information: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Share
>
> Point.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown.
>
> Total number of configuration settings run: 2
>
> Total number of successful configuration settings: 1
>
> Total number of unsuccessful configuration settings: 2
>
> Successfully stopped the configuration of SharePoint Products.
>
> Configuration of SharePoint Products failed. Configuration must be performed before you use SharePoint Products. For further details, see the diagnostic log located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_9_5_2014_8_57_34_865_858207425.log and the application event log.

PSCDiagnostics_9_5_2014_8_57_34_865_858207425.log error and Warnings:

> 9/05/2014 8:56:22
>   1 WRN  The Service ssosrv listed in the registry is not installed on the machine. Skipping stopping this service.
>   9/05/2014 8:56:37
>   9 WRN  The Service ssosrv listed in the registry is not installed on the machine. Skipping stopping this service.
>
> Error
>
> 9/05/2014 8:56:52
>   11 ER  R                Task upgradebootstrap has failed with an unknown exception
>   9/05/2014 8:56:52
>   11 ER  R                Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown.
>   9/05/2014 8:56:52
>   11 ER  R                An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown.
>   Microsoft. SharePoin
>   t.Upg rad
>   e.SPUpgradeException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown.
>   9/05/2014 8:56:52
>   11 ER  R                  Task upgradebootstrap has failed
>   Microsoft. SharePoin
>   t.Upg rad
>   e.SPUpgradeException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown.
>   9/05/2014 8:56:52
>   1 ERR  Task upgradebootstrap has stopped and failed.  Total failed is now 1
>   9/05/2014 8:56:52
>   7 ERR  Task initiate the upgrade sequence failed, so stopping execution of the engine
>   9/05/2014 8:56:52
>   7 ERR  Failed to initiate the upgrade sequence.
>   An excepti on of typ
>   e Mic ros
>   oft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown.
>   Microsoft. SharePoin
>   t.Upg rad
>   e.SPUpgradeException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown.
>   9/05/2014 8:56:52
>   7 ERR  One or more configuration tasks has failed or some tasks were not run
>   9/05/2014 8:56:52
>   7 ERR  One or more configuration tasks has failed to execute
>   9/05/2014 8:56:52
>   7 ERR  Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed in order for this product to operate properly.  To diagnose the problem, review the extended error information located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_9_5_2014_8_56_21_240_145717540.log, fix the problem, and run this configuration wizard again.
>   9/05/2014 8:56:52
>   1 WRN  The number of failed tasks reported by the driver is 1.

Comment: And what is the content of the file `PSCDiagnostics_9_5_2014_8_56_21_240_145717540.log`?

Comment: reboot the server and run again? what is your SQL server structure, single Sql Serve or mirrored or
?